# How to select <div class="ok">.....<a href="soft://an.id/">...</div> nodes?

Tags: html, xpath

A document has several `<div class="ok">` tags. I am able to select all of them with
`"//*[@class="ok"]"` (i don't have to specify div, because only div tags have this class). I get a list of 6 nodes matching this.

Now, i need

- either to test each node in order to see if it includes the tag `<a href="soft://an.id/">`. This inclusion is not direct. I mean, the `<div>` includes a `<table>` with many `<tr>` and `<td>` and `<span>`, and the `<a..>` (only one, or none) somewhere before `</div>`.
- or to directly select only (div) nodes of `class="ok"` that include this `<a>` tag.

I have tried many things, that all fail. Including protecting the "/" in the href detection (is it required?).
I am quite familiar with regular expressions, but i must confess that i find XPath syntax even harder to understand.. And the W3C reference documents are so hard, without examples..

Any hints are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to select only `<div class="ok">` element containing `<a href="soft://an.id/">` child element you can use the following XPath locator:

```
"//div[@class='ok' and .//a[@href='soft://an.id/']]"
```

Comment: That works like a charm! Thank you Prophet.
I was missing the `.//`. I tried with combinations of `/` or `*/`..etc,  with or without contains(). I was thinking that `//` means the beginning of the document. Apparently, `.//` means the beginning of the previously selected element. Am i right?

Comment: I'm happy I could help you. I have no time to search for accurate documentation, so I'' describe in my words. The dot `.` means from this, current node. Otherwise you will search from the beginning of the document / web page. One slash `/` means direct child or may reference to the node itself.  Double slash `//` means `some child`.

Comment: So my expression literally means: find element with `div` tag name and `class` with value `ok` **and** having child element `//a[@href='soft://an.id/']` below / inside it

Comment: It's short, efficient, and crystal-clear. Thanks Prophet!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have a  nested somewhere under the div with class "ok", right?

So in xpath, the a / is meant for a direct locator under/above the current tag. If you are looking for the  somewhere under the found div, you need to use:

```
//div[@class="ok"]//a[@href="soft://an.id/"]
```

Then you need to check if it exists or not by using some kind of an assertion.

Comment: Thanks Anand. But with it, i get all matching <a>, while i need all matching <div> (embedding the a)